Handling Rate Limits with OpenAI API: Seeking Advice
I'm facing an issue with rate limits while using the OpenAI API. My application needs to process an array of payloads and return responses to users quickly.

I've tried batch operations, but I'm not getting enough output.
Adding delays isn't an option as users expect responses within 10-15
seconds.

How do other third-party applications handle unlimited requests with GPT-3.5? Are there any strategies or best practices to manage this situation effectively? Any advice or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you! 

Rate limits are defined by OpenAI. To have bigger limits, change paying tier. Biggest tier allows for 10k requests per minute, 2m tokens per minute and 300m batches. IMO that's fairly enough for a lot of use cases. If that is still not enough, take a second API account and "load balance" between the two.

Also from their documentation: "If you need higher rate limits than this, you can request an increase in the limits section of your account settings."
